# SOAP WS over https

Tags: web-services, soap, https, websphere, websphere-8

I'm using WAS 8.5.5

I have the following req. :

1. I have a two web services deployed and I wish only one of them
   accessible over https
2. The rest of the applications deployed in the server must remain
   unaffected

I did the following :

1. Attached the WSHTTPS default policy set as shown in the [image: attached image]
2. Created a copy of WSHTTPS default, created a 'General Provider Policy Set Binding' named test(please see the attached images [image: wshttps_default_edited_policy_not_working] [image: Custom_policy_set] [image: Custom_provider_policy_set_binding]) and attached the both to the web service

In either cases, it doesn't work.
What I need is a simple guide to make a **web service accessible only over https**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can restrict access to a single web service to SSL this way.  I took your screenshots one step further and clicked the `SSL transport` link.  I get the following.

[image]

Notice the title says **Outbound asynchronous service responses**.  I don't think this is what you want.  Unfortunately, this is all you get when you click **New** for SSL on provider policy set bindings.

I would suggest bundling your "ssl-only" service in a different EAR and deploying it to a different server process.  You can then restrict that server process to only receive requests over SSL by disabling non-SSL web container ports.

If you want to get adventurous, you can write a TAI to check that SSL is being used.  But you asked for a simple way; and you have to dig in a bit to make a TAI truly secure (unfortunately, a lot of people don't).